# SP2013: Broken WSS_Content database is restored, some documents are not displayed

Tags: content-database, restore

Please tell me, after the fall of SQL Server the database was restored (Backup Symantec) only by 93%, after CHECKDB, a lot of errors in the DocStream table, which contains just the binary data, i.e. actually the documents published in the SharePoint server itself. I tried various fixes and scripts (CHECKDB), but all in vain.

Errors:

> "Object ID 181575685, index ID 1, partition ID 72057610849878016, alloc unit ID 72057611327897600 (type In-row data): Errors found in off-row data with ID 120324096 owned by data record identified by RID = (1:8406343:3)"

If you look at the web part, it opens a void, just the Ribbon panel and nothing, WebDav is empty too, this folder was not found.

Tell me what you can think of? Or somehow download documents from the WSS_Content database? Or use some software to restore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, no your database sounds like it is in irrecovarble state. SharePoint doesn't support more than an index rebuild with `CHECKDB`, e.g. it does not support the allow data loss option.

There is no 3rd party tool that I'm aware of to pull content out of a SharePoint 2013 or higher Content Database due to the shredded storage architecture.

Your only option would be to find a valid, functional backup of that database and restore it to SQL.